# Tryton 3.0: Always "wrong server password"

Tags: python, postgresql, tryton

After installing Tryton 3.0 from the ppa:rayanayar/tryton-3.0, as in the gist script on https://gist.github.com/sharoonthomas/5857450, I always get "wrong server password" when trying to create a new database via the Tryton Client.

Why is that? I've entered the global database admin password in /etc/trytond.conf as prescribed:

```
# Configure the Tryton server password
admin_passwd = my_admin_password
```

I've checked that

- the tryton user exists in postgreSQL and as Linux user and has his name and password in trytond.conf
- the PostgreSQL server ist restartet

  ```
  root@Tryton:~# service postgresql restart
  * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                             [ OK ]
  ```
- the Tryton server is restarted and running

  ```
  root@Tryton:~# sudo /etc/init.d/tryton-server restart
   * Restarting Tryton Application Platform trytond
  start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 50063: No such process
                                                                   [ OK ]

  root@Tryton:~# ps aux | grep trytond
  tryton   37312  0.2  1.0 292796 17368 ?        Sl   Mar01   7:45 /usr/bin/python
   /usr/bin/trytond --config=/etc/trytond.conf --logfile=/var/log/tryton/trytond.log
  root     40178  0.0  2.0 576524 34776 pts/4    Sl+  Mar01   0:03 gedit     /etc/trytond.conf
  root     50332  0.0  0.0   8112   896 pts/6    S+   10:45   0:00 grep --color=auto     
  trytond
  ```
- python is listening on port localhost:8000

  ```
  root@Tryton:~# netstat -tupan | grep python
  tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  37312/python
  ```
- the client shows the "create" button when entering "localhost" and "8000" in "Create profile"

Comment: Found that there may be something wrong with system user tryton: I cannot su into it. `su - postgres` works fine, but `su - tryton` just won't switch to the user. Might that be an issue?
`root@Tryton:~# su - postgres
postgres@Tryton:~$ su -
Password:
root@Tryton:~# su - tryton
root@Tryton:~#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so odd.
After resetting the admin password in trytond.conf to the standard "admin" the login worked again.

The "Creating database" info known from version 2.2 was skipped, the database was created, and in the "Configuring database" dialog a password was asked again (without hint which one), and it turned out to be the local database admin password (means the password created for the admin user of the newly created database).

Somewhat strange, but seems to work locally.
However, no connection via internet yet.

---

Internet connection solved as well.
It turns out in the end that the documentation for Ubuntu installation (on https://code.google.com/p/tryton/wiki/InstallationOnUbuntu), that currently refers the user to Debian installation, would benefit hugely from having the additional detail given in the installation for e.g. Gentoo, cause they have the actual working config file complete with postgre server settings, which was the decisive point in the end.

See http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Tryton.

I already had

```
# Activate the json-rpc protocol
jsonrpc = localhost:8000
```

And after adding this, it worked like a charm:

## Configure the database connection

```
## Note: Only databases owned by db_user will be displayed in the connection dialog
## of the Tryton client. db_user must have create permission for new databases
## to be able to use automatic database creation with the Tryton client.
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = postgres
db_password = postgrsqlpassword
db_minconn = 1
db_maxconn = 64
```

In my case, I have tryton as database user, some instructions prefer this, obviously for security reasons. By using postgres (the built-in master administrator for PostgreSQL) as database user, you can circumvent having to add the tryton role to postgres (the standard package install with apt-get on Ubuntu adds that automatically anyway iirc).